# Memory fragmentation affect sqlite3 performance

Tags: memory, memory-management, sqlite

I have following sequence in my application.

1. Download contacts from mobile phone using Bluetooth's PBAP.
2. Writing these contacts to a custom database created with SQLite.
   I configured SQLite with Zero-malloc option and given 1MB buffer to use as heap, and also using other optimizations like all row insertions in single transaction, `PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY`, `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF` and `PRAGMA count_changes = OFF`.
3. After writing to database I am reading contacts from database and creating speech pronunciations for all contact names. This speech pronunciation algorithm using dynamic memory allocations too-much.

Now, if I repeat above 3 steps, 3 times in a sequence in single execution I am getting following results.

**1st time :** contacts downloaded in 5 sec, database created in 10 sec.

**2nd time :** contacts downloaded in 5 sec, database created in 60 sec.

**3rd time :** contacts downloaded in 5 sec, database created in 500 sec.

Now I removed speech pronunciation creation from my app and repeated 3 times again. Now the result is

**1st time :** contacts downloaded in 5 sec, database created in 10 sec.

**2nd time :** contacts downloaded in 5 sec, database created in 10 sec.

**3rd time :** contacts downloaded in 5 sec, database created in 10 sec.

I found the issue with pronunciation creation, which is **memory got fragmented while creating pronunciations and it affected the performance of SQLite** for next time onwards.

But, I configured Heap for SQLite and enabled MEMSYS5, even the fragmentation affected.

Please give suggestion to solve this issue.

Comment: What happens when you use the standard allocator?

Comment: database creation time is 15 sec for 1st time and keep on increasing from next time onwards.

Comment: I found the issue is due to multiple mallocs and frees in pronunciation creation. I am using private Heap (Windows functions) in pronunciation creation, even though it is affecting database creation next time onwards.